# Get string data from generateDataKeyPairWithoutPlaintext()

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, key-pair, amazon-kms

I am trying to get string data from return values of AWS KMS call (Node.js SDK):

```
const pair = await kms.generateDataKeyPairWithoutPlaintext(params);
```

It returns both `pair.PrivateKeyCiphertextBlob` and `pair.PublicKey` as Uint8Array blobs. I need to make a base64 string out first and plain text out of the second.

I. *think* I got the first one:

```
const buff = Buffer.from(pair.PrivateKeyCiphertextBlob);
const privateKey = buff.toString('base64');
```

(though I am not sure) and I am really struggling to extract plain text out of the second. Something like

```
const publicKey = Buffer.from(pair.PublicKey).toString();
```

doesn't produce desired result.

Am I doing the first one right? How do I do the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I realized what I actually needed is PEM. So I put together this function:

```
function generatePem (publicKeyBlob) {

   const publicKeyInput= {
       key: publicKeyBlob,
       format: 'der',
       type: 'spki'
   }

   const publicKeyObject = Crypto.createPublicKey(publicKeyInput);

   const publicKeyExportOptions = {
       format: 'pem',
       type: 'spki'
   }

   const pemPublic = publicKeyObject.export(publicKeyExportOptions);

   return pemPublic;
}
```

based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mlmitch/7346fe1bcac7b85f4d345bca170ea576). And I just pass `pair.PublicKey` as a parameter.